# Ошибка с массивами C

Tags: c, xcode, отладка, mac

Есть простая программа с вводом массива, но на моменте ввода почему-то выпадает ошибка:

> ```
> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xefbff618)
> ```

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int m = 3, n = 2, array[m + n], i;
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    scanf("%d", array[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Следует прислушиваться к предупреждениям компилятора: *warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что при вводе с помощью `scanf` нужно указывать **адрес** переменной, куда надо записать значение.

```
scanf("%d", &array[i]);
```

или, как вариант -

```
scanf("%d", array + i);
```

Comment: Точно, даже не заметил. Спасибо.